# Using m2e, I want to create a .settings preference file during Update Project Configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt, smartgwt, m2e

I have a maven project created, and it all works fine. In order to get it all working fine, there is a manual step that I'm hoping I can automate with M2E somehow.  Here is a brief description of our flow

1. Check out project from source control
2. Using eclipse, right click on project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project
3. Right click project -> Properties. Make small change
4. package the project with maven
5. Run As Web Application (Google Web Application).

I'm hoping to have step 3 above automated. While it is easy to manually type in a path and click 2 check marks....every time a developer does a Maven Update Project...it wipes out that configuration...they often forget to make the change and call me in a frenzy.

If I have to manually copy a file into the .settings that's fine...i have the file (would need to filter it to add the version). I was starting to think down the path of the maven-eclipse-plugin...but it didn't look like it worked (it does work when doing a CLI mvn eclipse:eclipse)

For those familiar with smartgwt, maven etc....I am using the gwt-maven-plugin and I'm setting the Google -> Web Application options, making the following settings:

"This project has a WAR directory" = TRUE
"WAR directory" = (manually typed) target/myappname-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
"Launch and deploy from this directory" = TRUE

For what I had working in the maven-eclipse-plugin...i had:

```
<build>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalConfig>
            <file>
                <name>.settings/com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.prefs</name>
                <content>
                    <![CDATA[eclipse.preferences.version=1
jarsExcludedFromWebInfLib=
lastWarOutDir=${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}
warSrcDir=target/${project.build.finalName}
warSrcDirIsOutput=true]]>
                 </content>
            </file>
        </additionalConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
...
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything if you have the Google Plugin for Eclipse installed; it should automatically configure the project when it sees the `gwt-maven-plugin`.

Comment: It mostly does, with the exception of what I show above.